# Jsoup won't parse my website

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to get the title of the site, the code checks if the string contains the title is not 'null'. If it isn't null, it will execute the rest of the code.

```
try {
    Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://afterlifesolutions.com/theaterstore/app-featured.php").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    htmlContentInString = htmlDocument.title();
    if(htmlContentInString != null) {
        isNull = false;
            }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is

```
htmlContentInString = htmlDocument.title();
if(htmlContentInString != null)
```

The application skips that 'if statement' as it didn't receive the title. But the code is working perfectly on other websites.

Comment: does the html have a tittle?

Comment: did you log htmlDocument, maybe you are not receiving any thing?

Comment: @efekctive This is the website I am trying to get the data from http://afterlifesolutions.com/theaterstore/app-featured.php, and yes it has title tag

Comment: @Abdenaceur That is the problem, the code works perfectly on every website except mine.

Comment: Could you iterate over the dom and print out the elements soup has?

Comment: try to add a header to your request : Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("url").header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0).timeout(600000).get();

Comment: you could also search there doc with select() and if the text you expect is not there you have an answer

Comment: Why would you use JSOUP to parse your own website?  Unless you're writing a test, you should create a real JSON webservice and save yourself a lot of hassle and maintenance.

Comment: Your code works fine for me and sets `htmlContentInString` to the site's title. Tested with Jsoup 10.0.1.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb still facing the same problem

Comment: @GabeSechan I am just testing right now for future purposes

Comment: @TDG I can get the title, but when it in the 'if statement' it return true if I am checking htmlContentInString is equal to null or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is this something that you want but I think this might help you. I have some jsoup project with custom adapter and listview so I little adjust it according to your needs and I got this. Basically I wanted to show you how can you parse your html with jsoup. I'm using AsyncTask to get data from url and you should use to:

```
try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("http://afterlifesolutions.com/theaterstore/app-featured.php").get();
            Elements links = document.getElementsByClass("single-product");
            for (Element element : links) {
                Data data = new Data(); //class where I set and get the data, of course you don't have to follow this patern

                Elements getLink = element.select("a.product_link[href]");
                String link = getLink.attr("abs:href");
                Elements getImage = element.select("img.product_poster[src]");
                String image = getImage.attr("abs:src");
                String title = element.select("p.product_name").text();
                String price = element.select("p.product_price").text();
                Log.d(image, title);
                data.setUrl(link);
                data.setTopic(title);
                data.setBitmap(getBitmap(image));
                datas.add(data);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Method for downloading the images if you need it:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String src)
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        return myBitmap;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return  null;
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: This code  did the work perfectly, I had to add a 'isNull = false' inside the loop to check if it contains data or not. Thanks